# Unable to change attribute in powershell 4

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hello I tried to replace below attribute in powershell

```
ForEach ($usr in $users)
{   
        Set-ADUser -Identity $usr.SamAccountName -Replace @{officePhone=$usr.ipPhone}| Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*,$BaseOU"}
}
```

And i got an error like below

```
Set-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Replace' to the target. Exception setting "Replace": "Object reference not set to an 
instance of an object."
At C:\test\PhonesReplace.ps1:62 char:59
+         Set-ADUser -Identity $usr.SamAccountName -Replace @{officePhone=$usr.ipP ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

I take value from csv file and i looks like this

SamAccountName,Firstname,officePhone,Mobile,LastName,PayRoll
aserigad,Marta,+48225694,+48225694,Aserigu,203207

I am not sure why it can not accept ipphone even when this attribut exist ..

[image]

Comment: Your csv provided does not have a column ipPhone? Did you mean to do `-Replace @{ipPhone=$usr.officePhone}`

Comment: omg, right my mistake :)

Comment: Try: Set-ADUser -Identity $usr.SamAccountName -OfficePhone $usr.ipPhone